# Loading elements in Ext Panel using Ext ComponentLoader

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have defined a model type that represent an object with xtype 'image'. Now i'm trying to load this objects in Ext.Panel from JSON using ComponentLoader:

```
Ext.define('ItemModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'itemModel',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },{
        name: 'xtype',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'src',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});


var previews = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    layout: 'column',
    height: 500,
    items: {
        loader:{
          autoLoad : true,
          url: 'php/read.php',
          renderer: "component"
        } 
    }
});
```

But i get such error:

```
TypeError: me.el is null


me.container = Ext.get(me.el.dom.parentNode);
```

JSON which returned by read.php looks just like this:

```
{"items":[{"id":0,"xtype":"image","src":"img\/newalbum.png"},{"id":1,"xtype":"image","src":"img\/newalbum1.png"}]}
```

But if i'm create a 'store' with 'reader', and trying iterate loaded objects, it's works fine:

```
Ext.define('ItemModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'itemModel',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },{
        name: 'xtype',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'src',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});

Ext.define('ItemModelStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'ItemModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'php/read.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

var itemModelStore = Ext.create('ItemModelStore');

itemModelStore.load(function() {
    itemModelStore.each(function(record){
        alert(record.get('src'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Try just passing an array back, don't wrap it in `items`.

Comment: But only in Firefox and with error that breaks the further scripts execution. In IE page don't renders.

Comment: Error message:  TypeError: me.el is null
 

me.container = Ext.get(me.el.dom.parentNode);

Comment: I was wrong. It really works. Thanks!